# Specify the choices of the choice column in the JSON-code

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a Choice column in my SharePoint list, with these column choices set:

- Niet verzonden
- Aangevraagd
- Goedgekeurd
- Afgekeurd

What i am trying to accomplish is to create a button from that Choice column.
So when the user clicks on that button a Power Automate flow wil be executed and displays a Microsoft Form. The choices above will be set by Power Automate depending on the choice
the user makes in the Microsoft Form. The only think i need is to specify the choices of the choices column in the JSON:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"edf627d9-20f4-45ba-8bc9-4494bf2ff1be\"}"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDarker--hover"
  },
  "style": {
    "cursor": "pointer",
    "min-height": "24px",
    "min-width": "130px",
    "display": "inline-flex",
    "align-items": "center",
    "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
    "overflow": "hidden",
    "white-space": "nowrap",
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
    "padding": "4px 8px 5px 8px",
    "margin": "9px 0px 9px 0px",
    "border-radius": "14px",
    "border-width": "=if(@currentField == 0, '1px', '0')",
    "border-style": "solid"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "OpenInNewWindow"
      },
      "style": {
        "padding-right": "6px"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "Send to Manager"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this: 1. Do you need separate button for each choice option? 2. Do you want to have single button to run flow AND show the current value of column before the button?

Comment: Option 2 is what i mean :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using JSON like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "flex-wrap": "wrap",
    "display": "flex"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "box-sizing": "border-box",
        "padding": "4px 8px 5px 8px",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
        "display": "flex",
        "border-radius": "16px",
        "height": "24px",
        "align-items": "center",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "margin": "4px 4px 4px 4px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "class": {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "==",
              "operands": [
                "@currentField",
                "Niet verzonden"
              ]
            },
            "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgCornflowerBlue sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-CornflowerBlueFont",
            {
              "operator": ":",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "==",
                  "operands": [
                    "@currentField",
                    "Aangevraagd"
                  ]
                },
                "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgMintGreen sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-MintGreenFont",
                {
                  "operator": ":",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "==",
                      "operands": [
                        "@currentField",
                        "Goedgekeurd"
                      ]
                    },
                    "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgGold sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-GoldFont",
                    {
                      "operator": ":",
                      "operands": [
                        {
                          "operator": "==",
                          "operands": [
                            "@currentField",
                            ""
                          ]
                        },
                        "",
                        {
                          "operator": ":",
                          "operands": [
                            {
                              "operator": "==",
                              "operands": [
                                "@currentField",
                                "Afgekeurd"
                              ]
                            },
                            "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgCoral sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-CoralFont",
                            "sp-field-borderAllRegular sp-field-borderAllSolid sp-css-borderColor-neutralSecondary"
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    },
    {
      "elmType": "button",
      "customRowAction": {
        "action": "executeFlow",
        "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"edf627d9-20f4-45ba-8bc9-4494bf2ff1be\"}"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDarker--hover"
      },
      "style": {
        "cursor": "pointer",
        "min-height": "24px",
        "min-width": "130px",
        "display": "inline-flex",
        "align-items": "center",
        "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "box-sizing": "border-box",
        "padding": "4px 8px 5px 8px",
        "margin": "9px 0px 9px 0px",
        "border-radius": "14px",
        "border-width": "=if(@currentField == 0, '1px', '0')",
        "border-style": "solid"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "span",
          "attributes": {
            "iconName": "OpenInNewWindow"
          },
          "style": {
            "padding-right": "6px"
          }
        },
        {
          "elmType": "span",
          "txtContent": "Send to Manager"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Column settings**:

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks :) it works great

Comment: You're welcome, I am glad it worked for you!